# Identify 4x4 and 4x8 plate with clip

Tags: part-identification

Looking for part numbers of these plates with a belt(?) clip.

[image: lego]
[image: lego]
[image: lego]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are Scala Jewelry Plates:

[Scala Jewelry Plate, Modified 4 x 8 with Clip on Back](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3035clip&name=Scala%20Jewelry%20Plate,%20Modified%204%20x%208%20with%20Clip%20on%20Back&category=%5BScala%5D#T=C)
[image]

and

[Scala Jewelry Plate, Modified 4 x 4 with Clip on Back](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3031clip&name=Scala%20Jewelry%20Plate,%20Modified%204%20x%204%20with%20Clip%20on%20Back&category=%5BScala%5D#T=C)
[image]

Both could only be found in red in a single set in 1979: [Bracelet and Pendant 'Fantasy'](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=312-2#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
[image]